# Трудности с анимированием объекта, относительно положения курсора

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, анимация

Столкнулся с задачей: надо анимировать блок, относительно расположения курсора.
немного поразмыслив придумал такое решение:

```
addEvent(window, 'mousemove', function (e) {
var photoBig = document.getElementById("photoBig");

var coefX = e.x / window.innerWidth;
var coefY = e.y / window.innerHeight;

photoBig.style.transform = "translate(" + 
    ((1 + (coefX * (-2))) * 10) + "px, " + 
    ((1 + (coefY * (-2))) * 10) + "px)";});
```

но анимация получилась слишком резкая и некрасивая. 
и вот тут я уже столкнулся с задачей, которую собственными силами не способен решить.
каким образом можно реализовать, к примеру анимацию, основанную на кривой Безье, учитывая, что пользователь будет менять координаты мыши, до окончания анимации?
что можно почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Чуть подправил код, чтобы запустить. Div с фоновой картинкой двигается плавно при движении мыши. Пробовал в firefox и chromium

Comment: да, но я бы хотел, чтобы он двигался, сначала с ускорением, а потом с замедлением. а не так линейно. и еще медленней. то есть, допустим, раньше мышка была на координатах в 100, 100, потом переместилась в 400, 400. надо рассчитать на какое расстояние переместилась мышка в зависимости от этого выбрать время и задать более приятную анимацию. если бы это была анимация, которая не могла постоянно меняться, до ее окончания, все было бы куда легче.

Comment: Там объект двигается в направлении обратном движению мыши и на очень небольшое расстояние, так и должно быть?

Comment: да. однако, я хочу, чтобы он "вставал" на новое место, с некоторой анимацией. она должна быть медленней и не линейной.

Comment: попробуйте в css-свойства объекта добавить `transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;` Если это то, что вам нужно, попробую оформить в виде ответа.

Comment: нет, так делать нельзя. но это примерно то, что я хочу.

Comment: тогда поищите по запросу `requestanimationframe easing` или дождитесь ответа тех, кто с этим сталкивался :)

Comment: мне нужно лишь математическое решение проблемы, связанной с тем, что я не понимаю, как можно реализовать, изменение переменных анимации, заданной конкретной функцией, при чем с сохранением плавности перехода. спасибо за попытку помочь :)